# Couchbase Sorting

Tags: php, couchdb, couchbase

If I have a json document with a "created" field. And I want to 'query' with a view but order by newest first. Do I have to include the date in the key?

Or is there a more appropriate way of doing it. As I did want to have my keys as a unique index set from an atom counter. Such as "post::100".

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two options here neither of which include having the date in your key:

Option 1:

Have a created field on your document and use a view to output them in descending time order.  So assuming you have a document with at least these two fields (I imagine you'd have more) it would look like this.

```
{
  "type": "post",
  "created_at": "Wed Mar 12 19:19:33 +0000 2014"
}
```

Then with the following view (and descending set to true) you'd output your documents with the most recent being first. Also this allows you to do some cool stuff with grouping and the built in count reduce.

```js
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type == "json") {
    if(doc.type == "post") {
      if(doc.created_at) {
        emit(dateToArray(doc.created_at)); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2:

If you want to use an atomic counter to build up keys for your documents (a recognised design pattern) then surely you can just select the latest documents by taking the current value of the counter and counting backwards for as many results as you want and doing a multi get.

For example your atomic counter is at 2020, you want the latest 5 results so do a couchbase multiget on ids (2020 to 2016).

Personally I would recommend option one, it's how we use Couchbase and it works well for us, it's also more flexible when you take into account the grouping and range searches you can do.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will look further into option one. At the moment I have went with the atom counter and padded with "0"s using the sprintf function. This will mean when sorting by descending the order is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have an index that auto increments then it would be best practice to sort by the index. Otherwise you will be sorting by the date field which would be more time consuming.

Comment: Will I have to pad my index with many "0"? As say if I start from 101, up until 999 it will sort okay but what about when I hit 1001. Won't it sort 1, 1001, 2, 3 ... etc